# Minimize data to be serialized for Spring web services rendering JSON data

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, struts2

I was using STRUTS as a MVC framework till now.

One of the best features struts allowed was :
**A comma-delimited list of regular expressions can be passed to the JSON Result to restrict which properties will be serialized. ONLY properties matching any of these regular expressions will be included in the serialized output.**

Eg:

```
<action name="GetAllGroups" class="com.example.action.GroupAction"          method="getAllGroups">
            <result type="json">
                <param name="includeProperties">
                    ^groups\[\d+\]\.id, ^groups\[\d+\]\.name, ^groups\[\d+\]\.parent\.id
                </param>
            </result>
</action>
```

This will serialize only desired parameters of the groups list thus reducing the payload or redundant data (Eg: other attributes of group like create time, update time, members etc)

Now we are using SPRING MVC as we are migrating to web services and rendering JSON the data type for all requests.
With following configuration:

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

The controller API is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/groups", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<Group> getGroups() throws Exception {
    log.info("Getting all the groups");
    return myService.getAllGroups();
}
```

This is working fine, my only concern being the amount of data being serialized.
All the attributes of the Group object are serialized by jackson.

Using @JsonIgnore for unwanted attribute is like static binding. As it will ignore the attributes with @JsonIgnore for serialization for all requests where Groups are served to client. (Eg: To populate Groups in dropdown only their id and name will suffice, but to populate it completely on client as a profile, I need all data)

So my preference is a configuration specific to STRUTS, which can be applied for each request.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is create a new `GroupResource` class that contains only the fields you want to be returned from the API, and transform from `Group` to `GroupResource` in your controller method.

This allows you to explicitly control what is being serialized to JSON in your application code rather than relying on annotations and configuration of the Jackson serializer.

Comment: That would have been an option, but considering the dynamic requirements, I might end up creating more than a single GroupResource based on permutations and combinations of the attributes required.

Comment: In that case annotations in the Group class might not work well either. You could have you controller method simply write output directly to the `HttpServletResponse`'s output stream and maybe pass the object through a different serializer depending on certain conditions